# RankingMetrics in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, evaluation

I am trying to use spark RankingMetrics.meanAveragePrecision.
However it seems like its not working as expected.

```
val t2 = (Array(0,0,0,0,1), Array(1,1,1,1,1))
val r = sc.parallelize(Seq(t2))
val rm = new RankingMetrics[Int](r)
rm.meanAveragePrecision //  Double = 0.2
rm.precisionAt(5) //  Double = 0.2
```

t2 is a tuple where the left array indicates the real values and the right array the predicted values (1 - relevant document, 0- non relevant)

If we calculate the average precision for t2 we get : 
(0/1 + 0/2 + 0/3 + 0/4 + 1/5 )/5 = 1/25
But the RankingMetric returns 0.2 for MeanAveragePrecision which should be 1/25.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is your input data. Since your predicted/actual data contains relevance scores, I think you should be looking at [binary classification metrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#binary-classification) rather than ranking metrics if you want to evaluate using the 0/1 scores.

RankingMetrics is expecting two lists/arrays of ranked items instead, so if you replace the scores with the document ids it should work as expected. Here is an example in PySpark, with two lists that only match on the 5th item:

```
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import RankingMetrics

rdd = sc.parallelize([(['a','b','c','d','z'], ['e','f','g','h','z'])])
metrics = RankingMetrics(rdd)

for i in range(1, 6):
    print i, metrics.precisionAt(i) 
print 'meanAveragePrecision', metrics.meanAveragePrecision
print 'Mean precisionAt', sum([0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2]) / 5
```

Which produced:

```
1 0.0
2 0.0
3 0.0
4 0.0
5 0.2
meanAveragePrecision 0.04
Mean precisionAt 0.04
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically how the RankingMetrics function works is with two lists on each row,

1. First list is the items being recommended *order matters here*
2. Second list is the relevant items

For example in PySpark (But should be equivalent for Scala or Java),

```
recs_rdd = sc.parallelize([
  (
    ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],  # Recommendations in order
    ['item3', 'item2']  # Relevant items - Unordered
  ),
  (
    ['item3', 'item1', 'item2'],  # Recommendations in order
    ['item3', 'item2']  # Relevant items - Unordered
  ),
])

from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import RankingMetrics
rankingMetrics = RankingMetrics(recs_rdd)
print("MAP: ", rankingMetrics.meanAveragePrecision)
```

This prints the MAP value of `0.7083333333333333` and is calculated by

```
(
  (1/2 + 2/3) / 2
  + (1/1 + 2/3) / 2
) / 2
```

Which equals 0.708333

With

1. row 1 as `(1/2 + 2/3) / 2`

   1. `1/2` : 1 item in positions 2 or less are relevant
   2. `2/3` : 2 items in positions 3 or less are relevant
   3. `2` : Row 1 has 2 relevant items
2. row 2 as `(1/1 + 2/3) / 2`

   1. `1/1` : 1 item in position 1 or less is relevant
   2. `2/3` : 2 items in positions 3 or less are relevant
   3. `2` : Row 2 has 2 relevant items
3. And  `/ 2` as there are 2 rows